# dist upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04 and now gcc is broken

Tags: apt, upgrade, gcc

I've just done a dist upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04

gcc was installed before but now it no longer works

Command 'gcc' not found, but can be installed with:
apt install gcc

But this throws

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cpp-11 : Depends: gcc-11-base (= 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) but 11.4.0-2ubuntu1~20.04 is to be installed
 gcc-11 : Depends: gcc-11-base (= 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) but 11.4.0-2ubuntu1~20.04 is to be installed
          Depends: libgcc-11-dev (= 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

As far as I can remmeber I never did antthing special to install gcc on 20.04 so not sure why this is happening.

Comment: Odd that it says `11.4.0-2ubuntu1~20.04` is to be installed.  It's as if the upgrade to 22.04 hasn't completed yet.  Did you somehow stop the upgrade?  When something like this happens, usually I install what it wants me to install.  i.e., explicitly install `gcc-11-base` or whatever it needs to be happy.  But I'd double check that the upgrade was successful first.

Comment: Please add the output of `apt policy gcc-11 gcc-11-base` to your question - afaik gcc-11 wasn't available from the standard Ubuntu repos for 20.04 so perhaps there is a PPA involved?

Comment: There is surely no `11.4.0-2ubuntu1~20.04` version of [`gcc-11-base`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gcc-11-base&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) in the official repositories... That is most likely caused by an external source.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r got added at sometime.

I did apt remove gcc-11-base
and could then do an apt install gcc

Comment: If you skipped step #2 (delete the PPA), then the problem may re-occur.

Comment: Also, if you look at @user535733 answer and why he suggested "*Uninstall `gcc-11`*" and not `gcc-11-base` is actually for a reason as unlike `gcc-11` which is not an essential/important package for Ubuntu OS, `gcc-11-base` is an important one for Ubuntu 22.04 and shouldn’t be uninstalled. So, not a safe way … Also, since you’re new to this community, we welcome you and please have a look at https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2):

"*As far as I can remmeber I never did antthing special to install gcc on 20.04*"

Your output strongly suggests that you added packages from a non-Ubuntu source:

`gcc-11` is not in the 20.04 Ubuntu repositories. You **must** have added some non-Ubuntu apt source (perhaps a PPA) to get the output you showed us.

- Your output shows a classic version conflict. The #1 cause of such conflicts is wrong-version or non-Ubuntu packages. The package versions listed in your output are not from any release of Ubuntu.

**How to fix it:**

1. Uninstall `gcc-11` and all related packages from that non-Ubuntu source. Revert to stock Ubuntu.
2. Delete that non-Ubuntu apt source. It is not compatible with your release of Ubuntu.
3. Install the compatible version of `gcc-11` from the existing Ubuntu repositories.

Do the steps in order. Do not skip or ignore any step.